# How to set max height to scrollView?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

How can I set maxHeight property for scrollView?
I have a `LinearLayout` and I add some view (rows) to this layout programmatically. How can I show scroll when rows reach maxHeight of scrollView? ScrollView is located in a CardView

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/cardView2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_max="100dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewTitle">

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linear"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" />
        </ScrollView>


    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Because you're using `ConstraintLayout` you need to add 2 constraints to your `CardView`

```
app:layout_constraintTop 

app:layout_constraintBotttom
```

And you also need to add the following lines

```
app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"

app:layout_constraintHeight_max="300dp" // Change this to your maximum height
```

It should look something like this

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView 
    android:layout_width="0dp" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/card_radius_10"
    app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_max="300dp" // Change this to your maximum height
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" 
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" //Change based on your layout
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"> //Change based on your layout
```

Comment: It hides what view?
and in the Layout editor or on an actual device?

Comment: in the Layout editor? 

What constraints did you add?

Comment: If you don't see the card when you run on a device with actual content change the height of the `CardView` to `0dp`

Comment: When I try it like this: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/gilgoldzweig/06bfa827439ed1fb1d1ea101eb1361e5 it does seem to work

Comment: Hmm... Not working. Maybe problem in my second cardview. cardView2 is constrained below cardView

Comment: `app:layout_constrainedHeight` is pure magic by itself, thanks for mentioning it @GilGoldzweig!

Comment: add only app:layout_constrainedHeight="true" worked for me

Answer (score 2):

use this attribute in your ScrollView and change the LinearLayout height to match_parent

```
android:fillViewport="true"
```

like this

```
<ScrollView 
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"> 

        <LinearLayout 
            android:id="@+id/layout" android:layout_width="match_parent" 
            android:layout_height="match_parent" 
            android:orientation="vertical" /> 

    </ScrollView>
```

Comment: I need max height. Example: If item are more than 3 then show scroll else show items with wrap content

Comment: did you try to set weightsum in linear layout?

Answer (score 0):

> Change the height of parent View of your scroleView. In your case, CardView is Parent layout.so set the height of CardView like
>                   `android:layout_height="350dp"`
>   or use the weight according to your need by using linear layout in the parent of CardView. if you are using this layout in the Adapter or something like that then you only set the height with numbers.

Comment: It shows empty spaces if in layout one item two item

Comment: will you please elaborate where it is showing spaces? also repost the new code... ill check if there is any thing wrong.